# Scale elastick beastalk from lambda function

Tags: scala, lambda, ebcli

I need to run scale on elastic beanstalk in a lambda function that will be invoked by cron.

I can preform several actions on elastic beanstalk with boto3, but I can't find a way to scale the env.

What I need to run is similar to:
`eb scale 0`

Is there a way to do it with boto3? 
On can I run eb cli in lambda?

Comment: You should be able to run `eb` inside a Lambda function. Can you expand on what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Any lambda? 
I need to scale an env to 0-0 instances. 
Its a stage env, and most of the time the instances are not needed.